# appcmd command to set anonymous authentication on a folder under a Web Application

Tags: iis, iis-7, web-server, appcmd

I would like to run a command to set up anonymous authentication on a folder under a Web Application on IIS. I would like the particular folder to be the only thing affected. I don't want to change the anonymous authentication for the entire Web Application.

**Edit 29. July 2013**:
Still not having adequate answer :( Adding some key facts:
 - I need this in a script as part of installation process.
 - I don't want to rely on IIS powershell snap-in.
 - I know about possibility of setting this up via web config and I don't have a problem with that but I can't alter any config outside of my Web Application. I can't alter   C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config, so, this option is out.

This can very easily be done via IIS Manager (GUI).

Comment: I am sorry that I can not give you any advice, but I am really interested in the question and I am curious to see the answer here. Let's be patient, hopefully someone will know.. anyway, happy name's day, for its st.Anne today :-)

Comment: @Marzena well, you are seriously hitting on me

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10351075/allow-anonymous-authentication-for-a-single-folder-in-web-config

Comment: @ton.yeung will have to try on monday at work to let you know if that is what I am looking for ;)

Comment: @ton.yeung so I tried it, unfortunately it is not a solution. In order to make that work I have to change something in C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config. This is NOT what I can actually do on our production servers. Our operations do not allow me to do so because this might affect other applications running on that production server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `AppCmd` to allow overriding section configuration in application `Web.config`:

```
%systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\APPCMD unlock config  /section:security/authentication/anonymousAuthentication
```

Unlocking a particular section will allow child `Web.config` in a particular directory to apply. Just keep in mind that unlocking the section is applied globally.

Comment: I think it is the best I can get, so, I will have to live with that.

Answer (score 1):

Pasted from http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/authentication/anonymousauthentication ... This should give you an idea ...

appcmd.exe set config "Contoso" -section:system.webServer/security/authentication/anonymousAuthentication /enabled:"True" /commit:apphost
appcmd.exe set config "Contoso" -section:system.webServer/security/authentication/anonymousAuthentication /userName:"IUSR" /commit:apphost
appcmd.exe set config "Contoso" -section:system.webServer/security/authentication/anonymousAuthentication /password:"P@ssw0rd" /commit:apphost

Comment: I found that web page too... then I spent like 1h trying some commands  with no success. This is not what I am looking for but thanks for a try.